# Como salvar uma imagem no campo BLOB do bd SQL utilizando jsf + primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, imagem, blob

Possuo uma tabela no banco onde já existe o campo do tipo BLOB para armazenar uma imagem. Queria saber como faço para capturar uma imagem através do JSF/Primefaces e armazenar nesse campo BLOB do banco de dados.

XHTML:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{MeuBean.upload}" label="Escolher" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" fileLimit="1" auto="true" />
</h:form>
```

OBS: Utilizo o Firebird SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa Ewerton vê se isso te ajuda:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima eu cadastro um produto, simulando uma loja de brinquedos online.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa outra imagem acima, faço o upload da imagem para salvar no banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Resultado Final, que aparece quando faço uma busca clicando na categoria onde o produto foi cadastrado. Salvei a imagem usando tipo Blob no **MySQLServer**.
Nesse caso estou usando o **JSP** ao invés de **JSF**.

```
 public class ServletUpload extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {
static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
boolean isMultiPart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
if (isMultiPart) {

System.out.println("Upload Imagem");

FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);


String usuario ="";
String titulo = "";
String descricao = "";
byte[] imagem = null;


try {   
List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
Iterator iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {

    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next(); 

       if(item.getFieldName().equals("user")){
        usuario = item.getString();
        System.out.println(usuario);}

        if (item.getFieldName().equals("titulo")){
        titulo= item.getString();
        System.out.println(titulo);}

        if(item.getFieldName().equals("descricao")){
        descricao = item.getString();
        System.out.println(descricao);}     

        if (item.getFieldName().equals("file"))
        imagem = read(item); //Chamo método para converter a imagem

if (!item.isFormField()) {
if (item.getName().length() > 0) {
System.out.println("chama método");

Imagem img = new Imagem();

img.setTitulo(titulo);
img.setDescricao(descricao);
img.setImagem(imagem);


ImagemDAO dao = new ImagemDAO();
dao.gravar(img);    

HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("user", usuario);

response.sendRedirect("/LojaBrinquedos/Paginas/Admin/Alertas/Imagem/imgSalva.jsp");

}
}
}


} catch (FileUploadException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("Upload Failed");
response.sendRedirect("/LojaBrinquedos/Paginas/Admin/Alertas/Imagem/imgError.jsp");
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
}

    private byte[] read(FileItem fi) throws IOException{
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream is = fi.getInputStream();
        int read = 0;
        final byte[] b = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            out.write(b, 0, read);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();

       }
    }
```

A imagem acima é o meu **ServletUpload** (controller), onde eu recebo os dados dos campos quem estão na página de upload da imagem.

O método **read** utilizo para converter a imagem para o tipo **Blob** antes de salvar no banco de dados, lembrando que ele está presente na execução do **ServletUpload**.

No banco de dados para salvar você terá de fazer parecido com descrito abaixo:

```
ps.setBytes(3, img.getImagem());
```

Não deve ser complicado fazer esse processo para JSF usando uma **ManagedBean**.

Espero ter te ajudado, qualquer escrever ai.

Abraços.